# Теряется скругление краёв элементов при переходе от bootstrap3 к 4

Tags: c#, html, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc, fontawesome

Для странички регистрации использую значки font-awesome. И цепляю их к полям ввода. После чего скругляю получившийся элемент у краёв. С версией бутстрапа 3.3.7 всё работает хорошо.
Код:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Your Name</label>
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your Name" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.form-control {
        border-radius: 30px;
    }

    .input-group-addon {
        border-radius: 30px;
    }
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С использованием новой версии бустрапа 4.1.3 уже так не получается.
Вот мой код:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(i => i.CSurname, "Фамилия")
            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    @Html.EditorFor(i => i.CSurname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите фамилию" } })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Тутуже вместо `input-group-addon` необходимо использовать `input-group-text` а в остальном всё то же самое.
CSS такой же:

```
.input-group-text {
        border-radius: 30px
    }

    .form-control {
        border-radius: 30px
    }
```

А результат другой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так? Хочется добиться результата как в первый раз.

Вот последний вариант кода:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-signin">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(i => i.CSurname, "Фамилия")
            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    @Html.EditorFor(i => i.CSurname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtSurname", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите фамилию" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.CSurname, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.input-group-text {
        border-top-left-radius: 30px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
    }

    .form-control {
        border-radius: 30px;
    }
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример получившейся разметки:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-signin">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="CSurname">Фамилия</label>
            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="Требуется поле CSurname." id="txtSurname" name="CSurname" placeholder="Введите фамилию" type="text" value="" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="CSurname" data-valmsg-replace="true" id="mess"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: приведи конечный html а не razor разметку

Comment: @Grundy привёл пример в конце вопроса

Comment: увидел что в итоге editorfor генерирует у текст бокса класс `form-control text-box single-line` попробовал его использовать вместо .form-control в css, но это не помогло. Скругления как не было так и нет.

Comment: @Grundy я отписал комментарий в вашем ответе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В третьей версии это работает, так как в стилях прописано

```
.input-group .form-control:first-child, .input-group-addon:first-child, .input-group-btn:first-child>.btn, .input-group-btn:first-child>.btn-group>.btn, .input-group-btn:first-child>.dropdown-toggle, .input-group-btn:last-child>.btn-group:not(:last-child)>.btn, .input-group-btn:last-child>.btn:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle) {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
```

То есть, если `.input-group-addon` первый ребенок у него убираются скругления справа.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin', '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">');
```

```css
.form {
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}

.form-control {
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.input-group-addon {
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form class="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Your Name</label>
    <div class="cols-sm-10">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your Name" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

В четвертой версии bootstrap был введен дополнительный класс `.input-group-prepend` для добавления перед инпутом. Так как у тебя его нет, работает не совсем корректно.

В дополнении, так как в новой разметке `input` не последний ребенок у него не скругляется правые углы. Если сделать его последний все работает как нужно.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin', '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">');
```

```css
.form {
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}

.form-control {
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.input-group-text {
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form class="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Your Name</label>
    <div class="cols-sm-10">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></div>
        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="Требуется поле CSurname." id="txtSurname" name="CSurname" placeholder="Введите фамилию" type="text" value="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Grundy, да это помогло что бы не писать `border-top-left-radius: 30px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;` но у меня всё ещё не скругляется текст бокс. С правой стороны. В чём тут дело?

Comment: @Андрей, в ответа об этом написано. _В дополнении, так как в новой разметке input не последний ребенок у него не скругляется правые углы. Если сделать его последний все работает как нужно._

Comment: Grundy заметил такую вещь. Если это написать в виде html разметки `<input ...` всё работает а вот если использовать html хелперы уже нет. И даже если я хотя бы уберу строчку `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.CSurname, "", new { @class = "text-danger"})` а оставлю только `@Html.EditorFor(i => i.CSurname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtSurname", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите фамилию" } })` всё тоже скругляется. А вот с validationmessagefor уже не работает. В чём тут может быть дело?

Comment: @Андрей, посмотри на разметку: validation message это просто span, который после Input вставляется, из-за этого input перестает быть последним ребенком

Comment: @Андрей, просто вынеси его из input group

Comment: Grundy сделал вот так вот `<div class="cols-sm-10">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">@Html.EditorFor(i => i.CSurname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtSurname", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите фамилию" } })</div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.CSurname, "", new { @class = "text-danger"})
                </div>
            </div>` Результат прикрепил в  конце ответа. Почти)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87765/discussion-between-grundy-and-).

Answer (score 1):

Можно [указывать радиус только с какой-то конкретной стороны](http://htmlbook.ru/css/border-top-left-radius), в вашем случае - сверху-слева и снизу-слева:

```
.input-group-text {
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
}
```

Comment: AK а почему не работает так же как в 3 бустрапе? Изменилась какая то стилистика?

Comment: AK попробовал сделать как вы сказали, помогло. Но почему то теперь справа скругление убралось, хотя этот код я не трогал. Сейчас в впоросе приведу пример кода как у меня сейчас и скриншот.

Comment: Что теперь не так?